# Whats the xul id for this Firefox toolbar button "Open Menu"

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to get my hand on friefox customization, I would like to know th xul `id` for the "Open Menu" toolbar button which i have encircled in the image.

Found itd tooltip mentioned in `browser.dtd`

`<!ENTITY appmenu.tooltip                     "Open menu">`

[image: Firefox Open Menu Button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want #PanelUI-menu-button but the next level up might also be useful: PanelUI-button.

You can find out these kinds of answers yourself in future by using the Firefox Browser Toolbox and using the inspector functionality to just click on the element you are interested in. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox